# How to calculate the radius of a right triangle, having the sum of the two inradios of rectangular triangles inscribed in the greater right triangle?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, circles, tangent-line

Calculate the radius of the right triangle ABC, that is to say 'I'

If R + r = 20.

[image]

The three rectangular triangles are similar. The inradio of a right triangle has met its legs and its hypotenuse. To equal everything to r, i can put R = 20-r

Comment: Puede usted escribir en Inglés?

Comment: It is  English...

Comment: K thanks but the picture is now missing.

Comment: It is done.....

Comment: Please invent a better name than rectangular triangle.

Answer (score 1):

$$20=R+r=\frac{AD+DF-AF}{2}+\frac{FE+EC-FC}{2}=\frac{AB+BC-AC}{2}=l$$

Comment: Can't get much better than that!